# Can I get siblings with PHP's DOMDocument?

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have gotten some `h3` references in PHP's DOMDocument.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHtml($content);

$h3s = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h3');

foreach($h3s as $h3) {

    var_dump($h3->nodeValue);

}
```

I need to get the next elements after the `h3`s. In this case, it will be all elements up to the next `h3` or end of document.

It worked easily with a regular expression, but I don't want to use one here to parse HTML.

For reference, that regular expression is...

```
preg_match_all('/<h3>([^<]+)<\/h3>(.*?)(<h3|$)/', $content, $matches);
```

(Which is fragile, hence the desire for proper parsing).

So how would I get using DOMDOcument the data I expect in `$matches` from the regular expression above?

I checked the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), but couldn't find a equivalent of JavaScript's `nextSibling` property.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$h3->nextSibling` and `$h3->previousSibling` is what you're looking for.

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `DOMNodeList`, which contains `DOMNode` elements when you iterate over it.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

Comment: +1 It's important to check what class a given class extends in the PHP manual.